# Cherrypy form validation

Tags: python, validation, web, decorator, cherrypy

What do most cherrypy developers do for server side form validation?  I've done a google but nothing jumped out as "the one way to do it".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may write a tool and use it as decorator

Or you can use my Validation decorator:

```
import re
from simplejson import JSONDecoder
from simplejson.decoder import JSONDecodeError
#from cherrypy._cperror import HTTPError
from decimal import Decimal

class ValidationException(Exception):
    pass 

class ArgumentException(ValidationException):
    pass

class MandatoryException(ValidationException):
    pass

class DenialException(ValidationException):
    pass

class ParameterTypeException(ValidationException):
    pass

class ParameterValueException(ValidationException):
    pass

def validate_parameters(args,kwargs,required_args=None
                                     ,deny_args=None
                                     ,requires=None
                                     ,deny=None
                                     ,deny_except=None
                                     ,types=None
                                     ,values=None
                                     ,filter=None
                                     ,json_decode=None
                                     ,defaults=None):
    """Validates input parameters of a callable

    @param required_arguments:   list of types, Required argument's types  & counts in order
    @param deny_args             string ,regex pattern, if any argument matches with the pattern, exception raises
    @param requires:             list of fields to check for mandatory
    @param deny:                 string ,regex pattern, if any parameter matches with the pattern, exception raises
    @param deny_except:          string ,regex pattern for excluding fields from deny
    @param types:                dict of key:name and value:type to check for types, if mismatch it will be raises exception
    @param values:               dict of key:name and value:regex pattern to check the values, & fire exception if mismatch
    @param filter:               string ,regex pattern of parameters to filter
    @param json_decode:          list of string: field to be decoded as json data    
    @param defaults:             dict of key:name and value:default_value

    @raise MandatoryException:           if any param in requires does not provided
    @raise ArgumentException:            if arguments are invalid , short or mismatch type.
    @raise DenialException:              if found param in deny list
    @raise ParameterTypeException:       if parameter types invalid
    @raise ParameterValueException:      if values are not in correct format
    """


    #check deny arguments
    if deny_args:
        for arg in args: 
            if re.match(deny_args, arg):
                raise DenialException('the argument %s was not allowed' % arg)

    #decoding json parameters
    if json_decode:
        decoder = JSONDecoder(parse_float=Decimal)
        def decode(d):
            try:
                return decoder.decode(d)
            except (JSONDecodeError,TypeError):
                return d

        if isinstance(json_decode,list):
            decoded_list =[(key,decode(kwargs[key])) for key in kwargs if key in json_decode]
        else:
            decoded_list =[(key,decode(kwargs[key])) for key in kwargs]
        kwargs.update(decoded_list) 



    #check required arguments
    if required_args: 
        try:
            new_args = list(args)
            for at in required_args:
                index = required_args.index(at)
                if not isinstance(new_args[index],at):
                    try:
                        #try to cast
                        new_args[index] = at(new_args[index])
                    except:
                        raise ParameterTypeException('argument at index:%s must be %s' % (required_args.index(at),at))
            args = tuple(new_args)
        except IndexError:
            raise ArgumentException('argument\'s length is too short')

    #check required parameters
    if requires: 
        for name in requires:
            if name not in kwargs:
                raise MandatoryException('the parameter:"%s" is mandatory' % name)


    filtered_params = {}
    for param in kwargs:

        #checking requires
        if requires and param in requires and not kwargs[param]:
            raise MandatoryException('the parameter:"%s" is mandatory' % param)

        #checking for denial
        if deny and re.match(deny,param) and  (not deny_except or not re.match(deny_except, param)):
            raise DenialException('Parameter: %s was denied' % param)

        #value checking
        if values and param in values and not re.match(values[param], kwargs[param]):
            raise ParameterValueException('Parameter:%s does not meet value pattern: given value:%s' % (param,kwargs[param]))

        #checking for types
        if types and param in types:
            if kwargs[param] and not isinstance(kwargs[param],types[param]):
                try:
                    #try to cast the type too needed type
                    kwargs[param] = types[param](kwargs[param])
                except:
                    raise ParameterTypeException('Parameter:%s must be type:%s, given type:%s' % (param,types[param],type(kwargs[param])))


        #filtering parameters
        if not filter or not re.match(filter,param):
            filtered_params[param] = kwargs[param]

    #add defaults if not supplied
    if defaults:
        for param in defaults:
            if param not in filtered_params:
                filtered_params[param] = defaults[param]

    return args,filtered_params


def validate(**val_cfg):
    def validecorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
                if len(func.func_code.co_varnames) and func.func_code.co_varnames[0] == 'self':
                    new_args,filtered_params = validate_parameters(args[1:], kwargs,**val_cfg)
                    return func(*(args[0],)+new_args,**filtered_params)
                else:
                    new_args,filtered_params = validate_parameters(args, kwargs,**val_cfg)
                    return func(*new_args,**filtered_params)
            #calling the callable!

        return wrapper
    return validecorator

validate.__doc__ = validate_parameters.__doc__
```

Example:

```
@validate(types={'name':str,age:int},values={'name':'[a-zA-Z]{5,50}',age:'\d{1,2}'})
def my_controller(name=None,age=None):
    # process data
    return render(\\some template\\)
```

may help!

**EDIT 1**

Take a look at [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvalidate) package

Comment: Great code!  I like how cherrypy keeps you thinking the app is actual python and not a framework.

Comment: We can convert this code to a cherrypy standard tool. then process the validation at on_start_response and raise HTTPError on proper situations